# Devise and CanCan Roles Set By Other Users? (Rails 4.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan, roles

I understand the rather basic workings of CanCan and have tried to follow some tutorials, but none of them really discuss how to assign the user roles in my application.

Furthermore, I want my application to allow users to assign roles to other users. For example, my users can create projects, and assign other users to the project team. I am currently using a Role model to hold my user roles.

How do I allow users to specifically set another user to that project team role, where they can manage the project?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071693/how-to-get-devise-to-work-with-multiple-models-or-roles-preferably-with-cancan/21072344#21072344, which should answer most of your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a model with a field like can_manage_projects

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :roles

  field :can_manage_projects, type: boolean
end
```

And on your ability, you set a permission correspondent...

```
class Ability
  def initialize(user)
    can :manage Project if user.can_manage_project?
  end 
end
```

And so, you can use that permission whenever you want, doing things like:

```
class ProjectController

  def assign_user(project, user)
     project.users << user if can? :manage, Project
  end
end
```

or

```
<body>
  <% if can? :manage, Project %>
    <%= link_to 'Assign selected user to Project', assign_user_project_path(project, user) %>
  <% end %>
</body>
```