# How to Use CanCan with Role Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan, roles

I am using CanCan and have been researching how to get started. However, it seems that most of the tutorials aren't very specific, and don't suit my own needs. I'm building a social network where users can create projects and add other users to their projects, allowing those users to moderate that project.

I currently have a `Role` model with a string attribute, and a `User` model from devise. Where do I go from here?

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071693/how-to-get-devise-to-work-with-multiple-models-or-roles-preferably-with-cancan/21072344#21072344), but it doesn't fully explain how to set up the roles and the relationship between the Role model and the ability.rb file from CanCan.

If you need me to be more specific, please say so! I'm not the greatest Rails developer ;)

**Edit**

I have seen the railscast on this, and it doesn't have a separate Role model which I would like to have. I have tried using Rolify, but people have said it is too complicated and that it's possible to do it in a more simple way. I also ran into some complications so I'd like to just use my own Role model.

**Edit**

I'm currently using rolify and the roles are working. I found my solution at: https://github.com/EppO/rolify/wiki/Tutorial

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan Try watching this tutorial

Comment: Before being able to provide any kind of useful answer we really will need to know a lot more about what you're trying to do. Perhaps start by describing the `User` and `Role` models and how they interact with the other models you're trying to authenticate against.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your User-Role stuff is looking similar to following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, :through => :user_roles

  # user model has for example following attributes:
  # username, email, password, ...
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :users, :through => :user_roles

  # role model has for example following attributes:
  # name (e.g. Role.first.name => "admin" or "editor" or "whatever"
end

class UserRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end
```

you can do following:

First, extend your User model with a few helper methods or something similar:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def is_admin?
    is_type?("admin")
  end

  def is_editor?
    is_type?("editor")
  end

  def is_whatever?
    is_type?("whatever")
  end

  private

  def is_type? type
    self.roles.map(&:name).include?(type) ? true : false # will return true if the param type is included in the user´s role´s names. 
  end

end
```

Second, extend your ability class:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user
      can :manage, :all if user.is_admin?
      can :create, Project if user.is_editor?
      can :read, Project if user.is_whatever?
      # .. and so on..
      # you can work with your different roles on base of the given user instance.
    end
  end
end
```

Alternatively you could remove your User-Roles has-many-through associations and replace it with the easy-roles gem - very useful. It is available on github: https://github.com/platform45/easy_roles

Now you should have an idea how you could work with cancan, roles and all the stuff together :-).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I used rolify instead of easy-roles, but they do pretty much the same thing!

Comment: Was the answer useful / the solution? If yes, you could accept it ;)